# Determine column on which invoke custom function

Tags: powerquery, m

I am trying to invoke a function on an added column that will concatenate two columns. The catch is that I can't use the column name shorthand as I use dynamic parameters using strings to determine the column name.

Therefore the result is that I get a column as a List multiplied per row rather than the concatenated value for the specific row as intended

```
(func as text) =>

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataTBL"]}[Content],

    \\This is the string extraction process for the parameter
    funcTrig = Text.Start(func, 1),
    columnA =  "" & Text.BetweenDelimiters(func,"_","_") & "",
    columnB = "" & Text.AfterDelimiter(func,"_",1) & "",
    
    \\converting the string to column data
    Convert2ColA = Table.Column(Source,columnA),
    Convert2ColB = Table.Column(Source,columnB),

    \\function to concatanate column A value at a specific row with column B value at the same row.
    concat= StraightForward(Convert2ColA ,Convert2ColB) 
in
    concat
```

I have outlined with remarks the process and desired results, In the added picture I have pulled out the result of "Convert2ColA" what is the desired result will be 1999 in row one and so on.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite follow. You want the last column to match the first?

Comment: What does StraightForward do?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I want the last column(FNCheck) to have the concatenated value of the first(Year) and second(Month) columns based on M code I wrote that extracts the column names from the third column (Function).

So Theoretically if I had another 3 columns named Hours, Minutes, Seconds the code will use "Function" to dynamically find the columns it ought to concatenate so if the code was instead 1_Month_Hours the result would have been the concatenation of the revelent columns (Year not included).

Comment: @MichalPalko I didn't include the Straightforward code as it only supposed to concatenate a Text value cell with another Text value cell - pretty straightforward ;)

The problem I have is that the concatenated values return as a Record if I use merge functions on the two columns and which again I need one concatenated correct value per row.

Comment: Ok, are you sure StraightForward does not return you list? I think there might be a problem.